# Error Using Middleware in SLIM Framework

Tags: php, rest, slim, middleware

I have been at this for hours now and can not seem to figure out why it's not working. This my first time using SLIM and my first exposure to middleware. I am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html) listed on the slim website but just can't get to work.

My bootstrap code:

```
<?php

  require '../vendor/autoload.php';

  $app = new Slim\Slim();


  $app->get('/test', function() {

    echo 'Hello, World'; 
 }); 

$mw = function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $response->getBody()->write('BEFORE');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response->getBody()->write('AFTER');

    return $response;
};


$app->add($mw); 
$app->run();
```

When I run just my slim url without the middleware it runs fine. I get `Hello, World` as the output when I runt http://mysite/test. But when I add the middleware code as listed on the slim site I get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Slim\Slim::add() must be an instance of Slim\Middleware, instance of Closure given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/api/public/index.php on line 22 and defined in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/academy/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php on line 1267
```

Am I missing something? Does the middleware require some other setup? The slim documentation is not very helpful when it comes to this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: does it work if you remove `use ($app)`?

Comment: @BizzyBob sorry, meant to remove that. That was me just trying to get to to work but I was initially dong ti with `use ($app)` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try this $container = $app->getContainer(); $container["mw"] = $mw; $app->add($mw);

Comment: @BilasSarker I get `Call to undefined method Slim\Slim::getContainer() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/academy/api/public/index.php on line 21`

Comment: Just from taking a quick peek at the tutorial in your link, it looks like`$app = new Slim\Slim();` should be `$app = new \Slim\App();`, might that be causing the issue?

Comment: @IzzEps doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have installed Slim 2. You are also mixing Slim 2 and Slim 3 syntax. To install Slim 3 issue the following command.

```
$ composer install slim/slim
```

Then use code like following:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$app = new \Slim\App;

$mw = function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $response->getBody()->write("BEFORE");
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response->getBody()->write("AFTER");

    return $response;
};

$app->add($mw); 

$app->get("/test", function ($request, $response) {
    echo "Hello, World"; 
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Thanks. I just used you slim-skeleton to restart the project. Appreciate it.

Comment: In you slim-skeleton project, how can I add custom middleware classes to my project?

Comment: Same way as mentioned in Slim docs. In the skeleton I add the middleware in file: https://github.com/tuupola/slim-api-skeleton/blob/master/config/middleware.php